# Activating the traffic layer on GmapMap Vue Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a GmapMap component in my Vue site and would like to display the traffic on the map with a traffic layer that can be toggled on or off.
The following gives me the terrain layer activated, but I don't see the traffic layer.

```
<GmapMap ref="baseMap"  map-type-id="terrain" >
  ...
</GmapMap>
```

This is how you implement it in the normal non Vue way:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 34.04924594193164, lng: -118.24104309082031}
  });

  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: This may help you. https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/issues/238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Antonio I got this to work. It now displays the traffic all the time, so if anybody has a way to toggle the layer please let me know.

```
mounted() {

    this.$refs.baseMap.$mapPromise.then(map => {

      const trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer()
      trafficLayer.setMap(map)

    })
}
```